# How to append to a file in java

Tags: java, file

I open file as follows

```
private static Formatter x;
public static void openFile(){

    try{
        x=new Formatter("sarit.text");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Here I add a information to the file but the problem of adding the information to this file erases everything that was in the file before inserting the information

```
public static void addRecords(String age,String city,String name, String password){     
    x.format("    "+name+"  "+password+"    "+age+" "+city+"\n");       
}

public static void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You are doing `new Formatter("sarit.text");`

Checking javadoc for 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.lang.String)

> if the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size

you need to append to file.
Question [How to append text to an existing file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java) provides answers how to append to file in java.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using java.util.Formatter, the documentation specifically says:

> If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise,
>   a new file will be created

You have to find a different way to do it, with a BufferedWriter for example:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

The `true` parameter tells the FileWriter to append to the file.

If you want to use formatting, use String.format():

```
writer.write(String.format(...));
```